# Include Microsoft.Build.dll in Clickonce installation

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2015, clickonce, msbuild-14.0

I made a very simple app that makes use of VS 2015 build tools.
However when I try to install it to client machine by Clickonce Microsoft.Build.dll is not distributed, so app fails.

I checked Application Files dialog on Publish tab - but it is not showing the dll so I can not make it included. However the dll is present in bin folder.
The reference to the dll is added with CopyLocal set to true.

Comment: Have you checked the "Show All Files" checkbox in the bottom left hand corner of the Publish > Applications Files dialogue?

Comment: @GDavison, I did. And it does not show up. Unfortunately I can not post images due to zero rep.

Comment: The DLL is installed in the GAC as part of the full installation of MSBuild 2015. ClickOnce can't install or remove items from the GAC so you'll need to install the [build tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159) on the client machines separately.